# Returning output from bash script to calling C++ function

Tags: c++, linux, bash

I am writing a baby program for practice. What I am trying to accomplish is basically a simple little GUI which displays services (for Linux); with buttons to start, stop, enable, and disable services (Much like the msconfig application "Services" tab in Windows). I am using C++ with Qt Creator on Fedora 21.

I want to create the GUI with C++, and populating the GUI with the list of services by calling bash scripts, and calling bash scripts on button clicks to do the appropriate action (enable, disable, etc.)

But when the C++ GUI calls the bash script (using `system("path/to/script.sh")`) the return value is only for exit success. **How do I receive the output of the script itself**, so that I can in turn use it to display on the GUI?

For conceptual example: if I were trying to display the output of (`systemctl --type service | cut -d " " -f 1`) into a GUI I have created in C++, how would I go about doing that? Is this even the correct way to do what I am trying to accomplish? If not,

1. What is the right way? and
2. Is there still a way to do it using my current method?

I have looked for a solution to this problem but I can't find information on how to return values **from** Bash **to** C++, only how to **call** Bash scripts from C++.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited your question to fix formatting and make it clearer/more concise. Thanks for providing so much detail! Please see [ask] and the [help] if you have any questions about asking questions.

Comment: Even thought I applaud your enthusiasm taking on the task of writing your app in C/C++ to call `systemctl`, you might want to look at the GUI's `zenity` or `kdialog` (depending on your desktop), that are designed to provide a simple GUI interface to shell commands. Even if you end up writing the code in C++, `zenity/kdialog` are helpful for prototyping.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We're going to take advantage of the `popen` function, here.

```
std::string exec(char* cmd) {
    FILE* pipe = popen(cmd, "r");
    if (!pipe) return "ERROR";
    char buffer[128];
    std::string result = "";
    while(!feof(pipe)) {
        if(fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != NULL)
            result += buffer;
    }
    pclose(pipe);
    return result;
}
```

This function takes a command as an argument, and returns the output as a  `string`.

**NOTE:** this will *not* capture stderr! A quick and easy workaround is to *redirect* stderr to stdout, with `2>&1` at the end of your command.

[Here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) is documentation on `popen`. Happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this is perfect! Short, concise and clear. Awesome thanks again!

Comment: @Rhurac, No problem, and welcome to StackOverflow! Enjoy your stay!

Answer (score 5):

You have to run the commands using `popen` instead of `system` and then loop through the returned file pointer.

Here is a simple example for the command `ls -l`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    FILE *process;
    char buff[1024];

    process = popen("ls -l", "r");

    if (process != NULL) {
        while (!feof(process)) {
            fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), process);
            printf("%s", buff);
        }

        pclose(process);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but if someone copy pasta's your code, and it doesn't terminate where you thought it would, it would result in zombie processes. It never hurts to be explicit! :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response this was great thanks!

Comment: Your use of `while (!feof(process))` will result in the final line of output being duplicated. The proper manner is `while (fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), process)) printf("%s", buff);`

Answer (score 3):

The long approach - which gives you complete control of `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` of the child process, at the cost of fairly significant complexity - involves using `fork` and `execve` directly.

1. Before `fork`ing, set up your endpoints for communication - `pipe` works well, or `socketpair`. I'll assume you've invoked something like below:

   ```
   int childStdin[2], childStdout[2], childStderr[2];
   pipe(childStdin);
   pipe(childStdout);
   pipe(childStderr);
   ```
2. After `fork`, in child process before `execve`:

   ```
   dup2(childStdin[0], 0);  // childStdin read end to fd 0 (stdin)
   dup2(childStdout[1], 1); // childStdout write end to fd 1 (stdout)
   dup2(childStderr[1], 2); // childStderr write end to fd 2 (stderr)
   ```

   .. then close *all* of `childStdin`, `childStdout`, and `childStderr`.
3. After `fork`, in parent process:

   ```
    close(childStdin[0]);  // parent cannot read from stdin
    close(childStdout[1]); // parent cannot write to stdout/stderr
    close(childStderr[1]);
   ```

Now, your parent process has complete control of the std i/o of the child process - and must safely multiplex `childStdin[1]`, `childStdout[0]`, and `childStderr[0]`, while also monitoring for `SIGCLD` and eventually using a `wait`-series call to check the process termination code. `pselect` is particularly good for dealing with `SIGCLD` while dealing with std i/o asynchronously. See also `select` or `poll` of course.

If you want to merge the child's `stdout` and `stderr`, just `dup2(childStdout[1], 2)` and get rid of `childStderr` entirely.

The man pages should fill in the blanks from here. So that's the hard way, should you need it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer this looks like super useful information. I will definitely save this and explore it in the future. Thanks for answering so quickly!

Comment: It is not so much of a **long approach** as it is more a **lower level** approach. Both have their places, If dealing without output from a single command `popen` provides a simple interface, but when you need access to the information from parts of your code (multiple functions, etc...), `fork, dup, dup2` provides a flexible way to meet your needs.

Comment: True. If `popen` solves the problem, it solves it with substantially less code. This is the way you go when `popen` is insufficient.